# Presto SQL run on Windows error with fcntl.py PRESTODB

Tags: python, sql, presto

Presto How can I run on windows. I get an error related to the fcntl.py. Maybe someone knows how to fix it? Startup command launcher.py run

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\presto-server-0.102\bin\launcher.py", line 9, in 
from fcntl import flock, LOCK_EX, LOCK_NB
ImportError: cannot import name LOCK_EX